# How do I change the change the color inside the iframe - React

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I am trying to change the iframe body color via react component. But I couldn't find the solution how to do this. This is my src code. In the

```
public componentDidMount(): void {
    var frame = document.getElementById('myFrame');
    var body = frame.contentWindow.document.querySelector('body');
    body.style.color = 'red';
  }
```

But this is not working. I am getting the below error.

```
Property 'contentWindow' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2339)
```

Could anyone help to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which browser the issue is happening

Comment: Check this and see for which one you are getting the window property 
ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument.document || ifrm.contentDocument;

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's happening in all the browsers. Also the solution is not working.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting this element var frame = document.getElementById('myFrame');??? the error indicates that frame is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast like this:

```
 var frame = document.getElementById('myFrame') as HTMLIFrameElement;
```